# Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: PartialObserver<Object> | undefined): Subscription'

Tags: json, angular, api

i got this error trying to fetch through marvel api can you point out the reason please, thank you
it happens all the time idk why lol

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HeroesService {

  heroes:any[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.loadHeroes();
  }

  loadHeroes(){
    return this.http.get('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/akabab/superhero-api@0.3.0/api/all.json')
       // The error seems to happen here
      .subscribe((res:any[])=>{
      this.heroes = res;
      console.log(this.heroes);

    })

  }
}
```

Comment: you can remove [] from (res:any[]) and it should be like (res:any)

Comment: it throws a more sceary error ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[HeroesService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

Comment: forget to import lmao ty

Comment: @user2993464 You are just trying to remove types completely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loadHeroes(){
    return this.http.get<any[]>('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/akabab/superhero-api@0.3.0/api/all.json')
       // The error seems to happen here
      .subscribe((res:any[])=>{
      this.heroes = res;
      console.log(this.heroes);

    })
```

Comment: Ignore my last comment (that I've deleted now). It seems the code in the answer is actually different from the OP's code. It's preferable to explain in text, how the code you've shown fixes the OP's problem.

Comment: this is dead zone my friend but yout got verfication from already dead person

Comment: Such as Cigien said, can you explain how your code fix the issue ?